# location not set in listcell

Tags: java, javafx

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set. error received when attempting to load custom cell
All examples that I've found here on stack and else where on the web don't mention anything about this that I've come across

ListCell.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane id="CellPane" fx:id="CellPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="286.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Test.ListCellController">
   <children>
      <Label id="CellLabel" fx:id="CellLabel" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="3.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="279.0" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

ListCellController

```
public class ListCellController extends ListCell<Student> 
{
    FXMLLoader loader;
    @FXML
    private Label cellLabel;
    @FXML
    private Pane CellPane;

   @Override
   protected void updateItem(Student student, boolean empty)
   {
       super.updateItem(student, empty);

       if (empty || student == null)
       {
           setText(null);
           setGraphic(null);
       }
       else
       {
           if (loader == null)
           {
               loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("listCell.fxml"));
               loader.setController(this);
           }

           try
           {
               loader.load(); //Debug tools show error starts here
           }
           catch (IOException ex)
           {
                ex.printStackTrace();
           }
           cellLabel.setText(student.getName() + " - " + student.getUserId() + " - " + student.getAttendence());

            setText(null);
            setGraphic(CellPane);
       }
   }
}
```

It should be loading a custom cell into the listview, instead when it attempts to run the loader.load() line it gives the Location is not set error instead

I can't workout why it's needing a location set, I would of thought in this case it would get that from the listview it's getting placed into

error log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at Test.ListCellController.updateItem(ListCellController.java:51)
    at Test.ListCellController.updateItem(ListCellController.java:23)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ListCell.updateItem(ListCell.java:478)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ListCell.indexChanged(ListCell.java:337)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:120)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1708)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1692)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1818)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2721)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1245)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1206)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:576)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1748)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:393)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1086)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1174)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1189)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:273)
    at Test.ListViewTest.start(ListViewTest.java:40)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

best regards

Comment: I think the `Path` is not right in `getClass().getResource("listCell.fxml"));`

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]". Also include full error message and comment the line that throws the exception.

Comment: @Raw the path is correct if `listCell.fxml` and `ListCellController.java` are in the same folder.

Comment: the desired behaviour is in the first sentence after the code block. I don't know how to make it more clear for the problem statement, between the title and the first line I don't think there's anymore I could say. This is the shortest amount of code, considering I don't know how much you need to see

Comment: It appears to me that there is a problem in file `listCell.fxml`. However, since I did not find the contents of that file in your post, it's difficult for me to verify.

Comment: you did read the referenced help page, didn't you ;) Do as suggested or your question is not answerable and will be closed (most probably). Also the most probable cause for your problem is already hinted at: the fxml file is not where you expect it to be or the name is misspelled .. thriple check, move it, change its name.

Comment: unrelated: don't reload the ui in every call to updateItem. Instead, load it once at instantiation time and only configure it in updateItem

Comment: Thank you for the help, turned out I had misspelled the file name and I was too tired to pick it  up over the last few days.  @kleopatra can you point me to some resources that show how to do that, I'm a bit confused on how to do what your recommending